# Chil row en datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo una tabla (datatable) la cual hago una consulta en php. Necesito por favor saber como le añado un row expandible a cada una de las filas ya que no me deja de ninguna de las maneras.

```
<table data-order='[[0, "desc"]]' id="data-table" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Telephone</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Student</th>
                                    <th>Lang.</th>
                                    <!--<th data-field="Status" data-sortable="true">Status</th>-->
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Remove</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $teacher_query = mysql_query("select * from customers order by id_customer DESC") or die(mysql_error());
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($teacher_query)) {
                                    $id = $row['id_customer'];
                                    $customer_stat = $row['active'];
                                    $stu = $row['student'];
                                    $lan = $row['language'];
                                    $filename = $row['firstname'] . "_" . $row['lastname'];
                                    ?>
                                <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['id_customer']; ?></td>
                                        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" data-id2="<?php echo $row['firstname'];?>" data-id3="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>"  data-id4="<?php echo $row['cell']; ?>"  data-id5="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" data-id6="<?php echo $row['student']; ?>" data-id7="<?php echo $row['language']; ?>" title="Edit customer" class="open-AddBookDialog zmdi zmdi-edit" href="#addBookDialog"></a><?php echo " ".$row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname']; ?></td> 

                                        <td><?php echo $row['cell']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td> 
                                        <?php if ($stu == "" ){ ?> <td>-</td> <?php } else { ?> <td><?php echo $row['student']; ?></td> <?php }?>
                                        <?php if ($lan == "" ){ ?> <td>-</td> <?php } else { ?> <td><?php echo $row['language']; ?></td> <?php }?> 
                                        <?php if ($customer_stat == 1 ){ ?>
                                        <td><button id="btnSi" value="active-<?php echo $id;?>-0" class="btn btn-outline-success">Active</button></td>
                                        <?php }else if ($customer_stat == 0 ){ ?>
                                        <td><button id="btnNo" value="active-<?php echo $id;?>-1" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Inactive</button></td>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" data-target="#modal-default" class="open-AddBookDialog_delete"><i class="zmdi zmdi-delete zmdi-hc-lg" style="color: red"></i></a></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: prueba `responsive: true,` donde creas tu tabla y confirmame si a eso te referias con fila explandible

Comment: Gracias por responder @Victor, no me funciona con responsive.

Comment: me puedes indicar como lo pusiste en jquery?
https://datatables.net/ te refieres a eso con row expandible?

Comment: a que te refieres con row expandible?

Comment: Exacto, eso es a lo que me refiero. Lo pruebo y te digo a ver si funciona.

Comment: escribe el script para crear tu datatatable y te digo donde colocar, con responsive:true funciona

Comment: no lo consigo... me sale una tabla plana sin nada. No sé si habrá algún ejemplo en el que me pueda basar porque llevo ya casi 4 horas intentando que esto funcione. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a tu tabla ponle id="tabla1" por ejemplo

en tu jquery coloca
`$(document).ready(function(){
  var dt_datos=$('#dt_datos').DataTable({
        responsive: true,

  )};
});`

pero descarga el css y el js de la libreria datatable y enlazalo a tu proyecto, pero primero coloca el jquery

Comment: No funciona @Victor... he visto en el JS esto $("#data-table").DataTable({autoWidth:!1,responsive:!0,

Comment: Lo he solucionado poniendo en la tabla class="table table-responsive table-hover"

Comment: El problema que tengo es que cuando pagina no me funciona, solo funciona cuando la tabla sale entera sin pagination

Comment: Hola @Victor funciona si a la tabla no le doy un id, pero cuando ya está paginada no funciona, es decir se bloquean las filas

Comment: por eso se necesita el id de la tabla, el id de la tabla debes colocarlo en el jquery